# Rspec undefined method `children' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have an respec test. I have a Sizes controller and just trying to create a new size.

When i run the test i get this error and theres not much info on google about it.

**It seems simple but i'm really stuck. Can anyone help please?**

```
  1) adding size allow a user to add a size
     Failure/Error: visit sizes_path
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `children' for nil:NilClass
```

My test is as follows

```
require "rails_helper"
RSpec.feature "adding size" do 

    scenario "allow a user to add a size" do
        size = create(:size)
        visit sizes_path
        expect(page).to have_content("XXLarge")
    end

end
```

Here is Factory Girl

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :size do
        title "XXlarge"
    end
end
```

Here is my Sizes controller

```
class SizesController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @size = Size.new
    end

  def create
    @size = Size.new(size_params)
    if @size.save
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def index
    @sizes = Size.all
  end

private

   def size_params
    params.require(:size).permit(:title)
   end

end
```

Here is New View

```
<h1>Listing Of Sizes</h1>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><%= link_to 'Create New Size', new_size_path %></button>

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Size</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @sizes.each do |size| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= size.title %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', size %><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_size_path(size) %><%= link_to 'Destroy', size, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My layout header has children.

```
<header class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">SAFSY</a> 
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" >
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" >Womens</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <% Category.find_by(name:"Women").children.each do |category| %>
              <li> <%= link_to category.name, category %> </li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" >Mens</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <% Category.find_by(name:"Men").children.each do |category| %>
              <li> <%= link_to category.name, category %> </li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">   
        <% if logged_in? %>
          <li><%= link_to "Dash", users_path %></li>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Items<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "New Item", new_item_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Edit Items", user_items_path %></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mass Upload Items</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Upload Item Images</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Profile<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "View Profile", user_path(current_user) %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <li><%= link_to "Messages", users_path %></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Settings<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Edit Money Back Policies</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Edit Warranty Policies</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: "delete" %></li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Log In", login_path %></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</header>
```

Comment: Why have you got `<% @sizes.each do |size, ancestry| %>`?  Why isn't it `<% @sizes.each do |size| %>`?

Comment: Yes. I copied it from my other view. I still get the same error.

Comment: What is in your layout?

Comment: @japed You're right. It has the children method in it. Its a method from ancestry gem.

Comment: Anyone know how to make it pass? I need to leave children method there in the header. Otherwise my dropdown wont work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is embarrassing. Ive been coding for 13 hours. I was redirecting to `redirect_to root_url` it should be to `sizes_path`

```
  def create
    @size = Size.new(size_params)
    if @size.save
      redirect_to sizes_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Comment: I don't get how this fixed your issue, your test doesn't hit the sizes controller create method